# A statement about reduced row echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

According to Nicholson's linear algebra :

> The matrix $R$ has $r$ leading ones (since rank $A = r$) so, as $R$ is reduced, the $n \times m$ matrix $R^T$ contains each row of $I_r$ in the first $r$ columns .

Why this is true ? I don't get it at all .

Comment: What part of the sentence ?

Comment: Why $R^T$ contains each row of $I_r$ in the first $r$ columns ?

Comment: Can you prove it ?

Comment: I mean how we can prove if a matrix is in reduced form then transpose of it contains each row of $I_r$ in the first $r$ columns ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes but I want a proof for that statement . For being reduced echelon form , there are four conditions . How we can deduce that statement from these conditions ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust What is the form of reduced echelon  ? I mean how it looks like in matrix notation ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes , sorry for my bad . My problem is about the reduced echelon form .

Comment: The reduced echelon form is such that only $r$ rows are nonzero, as the rank is $r$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Can you show that in matrix representation ?

Comment: It's in your book, isn't it ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust No , it doesn't have a matrix representation for rref .

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=echelon+form&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK0-m9uZHhAhWKZFAKHbtTCVIQ_AUIDigB&biw=1680&bih=905

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ R\ $ is in reduced row-echelon form, then it must contain each of the first $\ r\ $ columns of the matrix $\ I_m\ $ among its columns.  Suppose the $\ j^\mathrm{\,th}\ $ column of $\ I_m\ $, for each $\ j\in\left\{1,2, \dots,r\right\}\ $, is the $\  c_j^\mathrm{\,th}\ $ column of $\ R\ $. When $\ R\ $ is transposed, the transpose of this column becomes the $\  c_j^\mathrm{\,th}\ $ *row* of $\ R^T\ $, and the first $\ r\ $ entries in this row are just those of the $\ j^\mathrm{\,th}\ $ row of $\ I_r\ $.  Thus, for *every* $\ j\in\left\{1,2, \dots,r\right\}\ $, the $\ j^\mathrm{\,th}\ $ row of $\ I_r\ $ appears in the first $\ r\ $ columns of the $\  c_j^\mathrm{\,th}\ $ row of $\ R^T\ $.

**Example:** In the $\ 3\times 5\ $ matrix
$$
R=\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&-1&0&2\\
0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
of rank $\ 2\ $ in reduced row-echelon form, the first $\ 2\ $ columns of $\ I_3\ $ appear as the first and fourth columns of $\ R\ $. Here, $\ m=3\ $, $\ n=5\ $, $\ r=2\ $, $\ c_1=1\ $, and $\ c_2\ =4\ $.

Comment: "If  $R$  is in reduced row-echelon form, then it must contain each of the first  $r$  columns of the matrix  $I_m$  among its columns. " Can you show this with an example ?

Comment: Thanks and how we can prove that ?

Comment: Prove what? The *definition* of reduced-row echelon form *requires* that if its $\ i^\mathrm{th}\ $ row is non-zero, then the column containing the leading coefficient of that row *must be* the $\ i^\mathrm{th}\ $ column of the appropriate unit matrix (i.e. contain a $\ 1\ $ in the $\ i^\mathrm{th}\ $ row, and zeroes everywhere else).